# Drawable ID's come zero

Tags: java, android

```
<integer-array name="ar_ex_1">
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_main</item>
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_1</item>
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_2</item>
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_3</item>
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_4</item>
    <item>@drawable/ar_001_5</item>
</integer-array>
```

I have this integer array, and I load it into Java using:

```
int[] arr = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.ar_ex_1);
for(int i: arr) {
   Log.e("anindya", ""+i);
}
```

The output is:

```
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
06-04 20:31:57.045 9360-9360/edu.usc.projecttalent.cognitive E/anindya: 0
```

I was expecting integers, (the values for the `drawable`s in `R.java`, but instead I get only zeroes. Is this not the way to load an array of drawables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is your drawable array in array.xml try this kind of code.

```
 <integer-array name="ar_ex_1">
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_main</item>
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_1</item>
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_2</item>
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_3</item>
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_4</item>
        <item>@drawable/ar_001_5</item>
    </integer-array>
```

Then in your activity, access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.ar_ex_1);

// get resource ID by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)

// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));

// recycle the array
imgs.recycle();
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It seems the easiest way, and the most generic one to solve the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use `array` instead of `integer-array`. `Integer Array` is An array of integers defined, it contains list of primitive integer. And `array` is an array of other resources, such as drawables. You can see in [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray)

Comment: Yes, using `array` did solve it. I was using `integer-array` because the drawable id's are stored in the form of integers, but making it an array solved the problem.